# NSUserDefaults для таймера

Tags: xcode, время, swift3, nsuserdefaults

Добрый день. 
Я правильно понял, что через NSUserDefaults нельзя сохранить ход таймера при не активном приложении?
При закрытии приложения и последующем его открытии мой timerLabel показывает время, при котором был совершен выход из приложения, и при новом запуске, таймер просто продолжает идти c момента остановки.

Comment: объясните, что вам надо сделать

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы таймер на 30 минут шел при не активном приложении.

Comment: просто чтобы шел или чтоб при неактивном приложении еще и будильник срабатывал или что то подобное?

Comment: у меня жизни восстанавливаются через 30 минут. каждые 30 минут восстанавливается 1 жизнь. Все работает, но только когда приложение активно.

Comment: запоминайте время, когда прибавилась одна жизнь, и ставьте таймер на 30 минут. если приложение закрыли и открыли заново, смотрите сколько прошло времени и прибавляйте нужное количество жизней. НАПРИМЕР: если при открытии приложения оказывается, что прошло 75 минут с прошлого прибавления - добавляете 2 жизни и ставите таймер на 15 минут, и сохраняете опять время, когда прибавилась жизнь в прошлый раз - 15 минут назад.

Comment: Это через NSDate делать надо?

Comment: ага. нц и NSUserDefaults тоже - чтобы хранить данные между сессиями